# Can I buy, download and play a game from PSN Store without Activate my PS4 console?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I would like to ask you if it is possible to buy a game from PSN Store and then download it to my PS4 console which is already activated as primary but with other console user and PSN account.
So actually I want to ask you if I can buy/download/play games without having my console activated to my PSN Account from which I buy the game.
If yes, will I be able to play games offline?
Also, will there be any problem if I use the PS Plus which already exists in the other user and account in my PS4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes. You can download and play the games you buy with a PSN account that's not a primary account on your PS4.

You will be able to play the games offline, but if I understand correctly you have a PS Plus subscription on the primary account of your PS4 so you will be able to play them online too. You'll also be able to play all the games of your primary account too.

Your primary account however won't be able to play the games of the 'new' user.

The only thing you won't be able to do is download the games to your PS4 remotely. (You can't log into the store on the website on PC and download them to your PS4 from there, you'll have to turn on the PS4 and start them manually).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to buy a game from my new account.